# How to change instance at OnInstanceConstructedAdvice?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

```
    [PostSharp.Aspects.Advices.OnInstanceConstructedAdvice]
    public void OnInstanceConstructed()
    {
        var instanceType = this.Instance.GetType();

        if (this.appliedTo != instanceType)
        {

            var LoadInDbMethod = instanceType.GetMethod("GetObjectInDatabase", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            var objInDb = LoadInDbMethod.Invoke(this.Instance, new object[] { null, true });
            if (objInDb != null)
            {
                this.Instance = objInDb;
                //postshot throws an error that this is readonly!!
            }

        }

    }
```

PostSharp doesn't let me to change instance once instance is created but I need a way to assign another object to this instance after it's constructed!

Suppose I have following code

```
var Pejo = new Car(){ Name = "405"};
```

Pejo 405 exist in my database with all of it's properties so I want Pejo to be my database object not a new object with null properties(other than Name).

I can also move from PostSharp to any other C# AOP framework that let me to do this.

How to achieve this with PostSharp or any other AOP framework ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should the whole aspect do eventually?

Comment: Once the instance is created I check database to check if my object exist in the database and if it's found in database then I want to assign database object to created instance! Suppose I have this code `var Pejo = new Car(){ "Pejo 405"};` This object exist in database so I want `Pejo` to be my database object. If you didn't get what I mean I can explain with some more C# code ?

Comment: @GaelFraiteur Added more information on question. Let me know if still you didn't get what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in the current version of PostSharp (4.0 at the time of writing). You actually would need to intercept the *call* to the constructor, which is currently unsupported.

A solution now is to use a factory method and implement the logic there.

Comment: Can you tell us that PostSharp developers are working to add this feature or not ? I can hold project for a few weeks if this is going to be added in version 4.1 or any time sooner ?

Comment: No the feature is not planned at the moment.

Comment: May you give maybe similar solutions to this ? Maybe a indirect way to hook all calls to constructor ? There must be a way to achieve this with current features!?

Comment: There is no workaround. You can add for a feature at http://postsharp.uservoice.com/ but it's unlikely it will be implemented in the next months.